# Is it possible to boot MacBook’s disk in target disk mode through a Mac mini/Mac Studio but use the MacBook’s display?

Tags: macbook

I have a MacBook which isn't very powerful. I like to use it normally outside my home, but in my home I would like to use a Mac mini or Mac Studio. However, I still want to boot from the MacBook.

I have used target disk mode so I know how to set that up, but I was wondering:

1. Is there any way to use the display of the MacBook (which is in target disk mode) as the main display (This is the main question I would like answered.)
2. What cables and ports should I use for target disk mode so I have good read/write speeds? (I don’t really care if this gets answered but if the first question get answered this would be useful to know.)

I would like to use the better CPU and RAM in a desktop version so that if something were to happen to the MacBook it would be possible to recover without an enormous cost.

I already back it up regularly. However, I am not sure if it is possible to use the display of the MacBook during target disk mode, which is what I want to achive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. There was a thing called "[Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)" that a few models of iMacs supported several years ago, that allowed the iMac's screen to be used as an external display for another machine. But it never came to any form of MacBook and even iMacs don't support it anymore.
2. Thunderbolt. Use the fastest form of Thunderbolt that both machines support. But note that Target Disk Mode is more of a recovery / in-a-pinch kind of feature, not necessarily designed for optimal performance or everyday use.